# How to set layout of Work Item Tracking Custom Control for printing

Tags: custom-controls, tfs-workitem

I developed WIT custom control. The control used xml serialization to store complex data as value. One of must have requirement is printing support. As it expected the control value is displayed in serialized view when user tried to print work item form that contains the control.

I couldn't find any way to deserialize the value of the custom control and set layout before printing.

Does anybody know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is normally done is:

1. create a backing field containing the xml data
2. create a second field containing the display data

When the display data changes, update the backing field accordingly and vice versa using the when rules. (Check out the Priority field for an example on how you could do this).

Now it's easy to print something else than xml, but it's still hard to create a graphical representation.

Comment: Thank you Jesse. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @Rapax: If jessehouwing's answer was helpful you might want to upvote it and/or mark it as an answer.